# Joiner - skipDuplicates

Tags: guava

I have a situation where I want to remove duplicates from a collection (list) and then join them.
I wanted to make an extension for Joiner, but it is impossible as all constructors are private.

Here's a code snippet of what we did:

```java
Collection<String> tokens = newArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < numOfFoundTitles; i++) {
    if (!tokens.contains(titlesInRange.get(i).titleAsTokens)) {
        tokens.add(titlesInRange.get(i).getTitleAsTokens());
    }
}
return titleTokensJoiner.join(tokens);
```

Any suggestions?
I thought about Function / Predicate, but they are not suitable there.

Thanks

Eyal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
return titleTokensJoiner.join(ImmutableSet.copyOf(tokens));
```

Short, sweet, and correct.  `ImmutableSet` preserves the order of the original input, but ignores repeated occurrences of an element after the first occurrence.

Comment: Wow! thanks. Only the copyOf is on tokens and not titlesInRange :) (copy past -> fail test)

Comment: ...No, this should work, and you shouldn't be creating `tokens` at all, let alone copying it into an `ImmutableSet`.  Can you describe the test that's failing?

Comment: titlesInRange is not a String. I did not show all of the code. Here it is:    private String createTokensString(List<TitleSourceScore> titlesInRange) {
        int numOfFoundTitles = Math.min(numberOfTitlesToTokenize, titlesInRange.size());
        
        Collection<String> tokens = newArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfFoundTitles; i++) {
                tokens.add(titlesInRange.get(i).getTitleAsTokens());
        }
        return titleTokensJoiner.join(ImmutableSet.copyOf(tokens));
    }

Comment: sorry for the way it looks... I can't seem to format it. but you can see that I extract the token from the title in range object

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense now, I think?  I'm not clear on whether you want to collect each of the unique tokens, or the unique titles, which could make the situation more complicated.

Comment: the parameter's name is misleading. It is a class that holds some data, title included. also, it holds the title as tokens, and i am collecting this. I guess I need to change the name :)

Comment: `ImmutableSet.copyOf(tokens)` eliminates duplicate tokens, not titles, and I'm not sure that's actually what you want.

Comment: Thanks. (SO asked me to avoid extended discussions in comment. so i will stop) :)